# How to apply same operation to multiple columns spread out in dataframe in R?

Tags: r, loops, data-cleaning

beginner here!
I have a dataframe with over 600 columns. I want to apply some simple operations to specific columns that are all named similarly (see example below) but spread out throughout the dataframe. How can I build a loop for all these columns based on their names and the ascending numbers at the end of the column name?

Dataframe example:

```
Name  Col_x_1  Company  Col_x_2  Start_Year  End_Year  Col_x_3
asd   4 Col    Test     2 Col    1902        1933      1 Col
kfj   5 Cols   Test_2   10 Col   1933        1954      0
ale   0        Test_3   11 Cols  1988        1999      5 Col
...
```

Output example: I want to remove the string following the space behind the value in the columns named "Col_x_1, Col_x_2, ..." (going up until 56) and turn the columns into dbl.

```
Name  Col_x_1  Company  Col_x_2  Start_Year  End_Year  Col_x_3
asd   4        Test     2        1902        1933      1 
kfj   5        Test_2   10       1933        1954      0
ale   0        Test_3   11       1988        1999      5 
...
```

How can I build a loop to perform this simple operation? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Col_x"), ~str_extract(., "^\\d+") %>% as.numeric()))
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  Name  Col_x_1 Company Col_x_2 Start_Year End_Year Col_x_3
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 asd         4 Test          2       1902     1933       1
2 kfj         5 Test_2       10       1933     1954       0
3 ale         0 Test_3       11       1988     1999       5
```

Or, depending on your actual data

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Col_x"), ~str_remove_all(., "(?<=\\d)\\s+[A-z]+") %>% as.numeric()))
```

The first one extracts the starting number (assuming it's an integer) and removes the remaining content.
The second one looks for a number followed by a space and some letters and removes them.

Finally both convert the remaining part into a numeric.

We use `starts_with()` to select the columns by a names pattern. There are other possibilities like `ends_with()`, `matches()` or `contains()`. The selection of the appropriate function depends on the actual structure of the names.

Comment: Thank you!! Not sure why but when I try this code with my real dataset, the conversion of the columns only starts at column _31, the columns before that are not converted. Do you have an idea why? The name of the column is always the same

Comment: Perhaps the columns have a different names pattern? Like "Col_x_2" and "col_x 3"?

Comment: No the name pattern is exactly the same, there is no difference

Comment: Even no hidden spaces or cspitalized letters?

Comment: No, I originally used a code to replicate the column names so there should not be any differences, hidden spaces of capitalization, as I did not name these columns manually

Comment: The code above should be applied to the whole dataframe. Regarding your problem: I don't have an idea, in this case I need to see the `names(df)` of your dataframe.

Comment: ```names(df)``` gives this output for a sample of the columns - I want to change the columns "Team_Num_ICOs_x":    
 [75] "Team_1"   
 [76] "Team_Desc_1"               
 [77] "Team_URL_1"                
 [78] "Team_Ver_1"                
 [79] "Team_Num_ICOs_1"           
 [80] "Team_Value_ICOs_1"         
 [81] "Team_2"    
 [82] "Team_Desc_2"
 [83] "Team_URL_2" 
 [84] "Team_Ver_2"    
 [85] "Team_Num_ICOs_2" 
 [86] "Team_Value_ICOs_2" 
 [87] "Team_3"            
 [88] "Team_Desc_3"
 [89] "Team_URL_3" [90] "Team_Ver_3" 
 [91] "Team_Num_ICOs_3" [92] "Team_Value_ICOs_3"

Comment: Are you using `starts_with("Team_Num_ICO")`?

Comment: I am using ```starts_with("Team_Num_ICOs_")```

Comment: @Soph2010 Sorry, don't know a solution for your problem. Based on the data I saw I think the shown solution should work.

Comment: Not sure but seemingly a simple mistake, I cleaned up my Global Environment and restarted the session and somehow it now works!

Answer (score 0):

If you **must** use a loop, you could use `grep` to get the columns names that contains "Col_x_" in the beginning and `gsub` to remove the words that you want

```
names_dat <- grep("^Col_x_",names(dat), value = TRUE)
for (i in names_dat) {
  dat[[i]] <- as.numeric(gsub("Cols?","", dat[[i]]))
}
```

Comment: This converts my df in class character somehow?